# createChooser null pointer exception

Tags: android

```
Uri selectedUri = Uri.fromFile(selected.getAbsoluteFile());
String fileExtension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(selectedUri.toString());
String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExtension);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(selectedUri, mimeType);
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open File...");
startActivity(chooser);
```

This code used to always work, meaning that even if no activities were found to handle the intent, chooser dialog would still appear stating such. Now this code throws a NullPointerException (version 4.3) if there's no activities found to populate the chooser dialog. Has anyone else experienced this or know something I may be doing wrong?

Logcat:

```
02-25 17:03:24.260: E/AndroidRuntime(13502): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 17:03:24.260: E/AndroidRuntime(13502): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-25 17:03:24.260: E/AndroidRuntime(13502):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2517)
02-25 17:03:24.260: E/AndroidRuntime(13502):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2574)
02-25 17:03:24.260: E/AndroidRuntime(13502):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
02-25 17:03:24.260: E/AndroidRuntime(13502):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1413)
02-25 17:03:24.260: E/AndroidRuntime(13502):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-25 17:03:24.260: E/AndroidRuntime(13502):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
02-25 17:03:24.260: E/AndroidRuntime(13502):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
02-25 17:03:24.260: E/AndroidRuntime(13502):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 17:03:24.260: E/AndroidRuntime(13502):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-25 17:03:24.260: E/AndroidRuntime(13502):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
02-25 17:03:24.260: E/AndroidRuntime(13502):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:843)
02-25 17:03:24.260: E/AndroidRuntime(13502):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-25 17:03:24.260: E/AndroidRuntime(13502): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-25 17:03:24.260: E/AndroidRuntime(13502):    at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.checkListHeight(ResolverActivity.java:299)
02-25 17:03:24.260: E/AndroidRuntime(13502):    at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.onCreate(ResolverActivity.java:219)
02-25 17:03:24.260: E/AndroidRuntime(13502):    at com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity.onCreate(ChooserActivity.java:53)
02-25 17:03:24.260: E/AndroidRuntime(13502):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5195)
02-25 17:03:24.260: E/AndroidRuntime(13502):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
02-25 17:03:24.260: E/AndroidRuntime(13502):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2473)
02-25 17:03:24.260: E/AndroidRuntime(13502):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: where does it throw the NPE? post your logcat.

Comment: Ok, I added logcat, NPE appears to occur in ResolverActivity.checkListHeight

Comment: have you tried stepping through with a debugger? I'm wondering if fileExtension or mimeType are null perhaps?

Comment: I have stepped thru and those are not null. I'm trying to open a .csv file in this case without a .csv viewer on device. mimeType = text/comma-separated-values. In this example I'm attempting to use a file uri: file:///storage/emulated/0/Journals/Accounts_1393273518324.csv. I spent time changing it to content uri with same results.

Comment: My solution is going to be to abandon Intent.createChooser and wrap my startActivity call in try/catch block. The reason I used createChooser initially was because of this very scenario, it did work prior to 4.3.